# Clone Active Directory Domain Services

Tags: windows, azure, active-directory

I have a Azure VM running Win server 2012 r2 datacenter. I have installed Active Directory Domain Services Role onto that VM. Now i want to Clone it with the same ADDS settings to create new VMs.

I tried Sysprep, but later i found out that sysprep doesnt support ADDS.

Is there any possible way ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You have to install and promote each domain controller in your forest.

However, using powershell + Azure Custom Script VM Extension you can automate the process.

> Custom Script extension for Windows allows you to run PowerShell
>   scripts on a remote VM, without logging into it. The scripts can be
>   run after provisioning the VM or any time during the lifecycle of the
>   VM without requiring to open any additional ports on the VM. The most
>   common use case for Custom Script Extension include running,
>   installing, and configuring additional software on the VM after it's
>   provisioned.

**More info:**

[Custom Script extension for Windows virtual machines](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-extensions-customscript/)

[Step-by-Step: Auto-join a VM to ADDS in the Azure Cloud](http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2014/07/28/step-by-step-auto-join-a-member-server-vm-to-active-directory-domain-in-the-azure-cloud-with-vm-agent-custom-script-extension.aspx)